# ScriptManager AsyncPostBackTimeout working locally, but not on remote clients

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-ajax, scriptmanager

On one aspx page in ASP.NET 3.5 C# application, when I select certain input parameters and click the Submit button, a back-end database query runs for about 6 minutes and updates the gridview with its results. This gridview is in UpdatePanel which has the Submit button as AsyncPostBackTrigger.

Since the default timeout is 90 seconds, I increased ScriptManager AsyncPostBackTimeout to 600 (10 minutes, just to be safe). When I run the app locally (localhost), the gridview is updated as expected. But when I access this app from a different client machine, it keeps running for 10 minutes and doesn't update the gridview at the end, even though the backend query has finished in 6 minutes.

```
http://localhost/appname/page.aspx (works)
http://another_ip/appname/page.aspx (same web server, different client machine, doesn't work).
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: 6 minutes to run a query? Jesus.

Comment: hi, you have set your server with the specified ip address such that it can be shareable. In your web site properties window > Home Directory section you need to set the items properly. Check it once then come back again.